# MPAndroidChart combined chart bar + line with space

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to create a combined chart with 2 barcharts and one linechart datasets. X axis should be same for all datasets. Between barcharts should be a 300% space set with BarData setGroupSpace(300f). And this is the problem, I am not able to make linechart have this space too, so that the point of linechart would be always between this 2 bars. But it looks like linechart has its own X axis.. Also the labels on X axis should be shifted to be centered with 2 bars.
Any hints how to do it ?

[image]

```
private void setupChart(){

    chart.setDrawOrder(new CombinedChart.DrawOrder[]{CombinedChart.DrawOrder.BAR, CombinedChart.DrawOrder.BUBBLE, CombinedChart.DrawOrder.CANDLE,
            CombinedChart.DrawOrder.LINE, CombinedChart.DrawOrder.SCATTER});

    chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    XAxis x = chart.getXAxis();
    x.setTextSize(14f);
    x.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

    YAxis y = chart.getAxisLeft();
    y.setEnabled(false);

    chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    chart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10f);
    chart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(10f);
    chart.setDescription("");

    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < itemcount; i++) {
        String timeString = formatter.format(i * 1000);
        labels.add(timeString);
    }
    CombinedData data = new CombinedData(labels);

    data.setData(generateLineData());
    data.setData(generateBarData());
    chart.setData(data);

    GraphPopup popup = new GraphPopup(this, R.layout.view_graph_tooltip);
    chart.setMarkerView(popup);

    Legend legend = chart.getLegend();
    legend.setTextSize(14f);
    legend.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.BELOW_CHART_CENTER);

    //chart.animateY(2000);
    chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10f);
    chart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(10f);
    chart.moveViewToX(entries1.size());

    buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dataset0.addEntry(new BarEntry(3, dataset0.getEntryCount()));
            dataset1.addEntry(new BarEntry(12, dataset1.getEntryCount()));
           // labels.add(labels.size(), "x" + labels.size());
            chart.notifyDataSetChanged(); // let the chart know it's data changed
            chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10f);
            chart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(10f);
            chart.moveViewToX(entries1.size());
            //chart.invalidate(); // refresh
        }
    });
}

private LineData generateLineData() {

    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++) {
        entries.add(new Entry(rand.nextInt(22), index));
        String timeString = formatter.format(index * 3600*24*1000);
        labels.add(timeString);
    }

    LineData d = new LineData(labels);
    LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(entries, "Line DataSet");
    set.setColor(Color.RED);
    set.setLineWidth(2.5f);
    set.setCircleColor(Color.RED);
    set.setCircleSize(5f);
    set.setFillColor(Color.WHITE);
    set.setDrawCubic(true);
    set.setDrawValues(true);
    set.setValueTextSize(10f);
    set.setValueTextColor(Color.RED);
    set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

    d.addDataSet(set);

    return d;
}

private BarData generateBarData() {

    ArrayList<String> labels0 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < itemcount; i++) {
        BarEntry entry = new BarEntry(rand.nextInt(22) + 8, i);
        entries.add(entry);
        String timeString = formatter.format(i * 3600*24*1000);
        labels0.add(timeString);
    }

    dataset0.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.graph_bar));
    dataset0.setHighLightColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.graph_bar_selected));
    dataset0.setBarSpacePercent(0f);

    ArrayList<String> labels1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int j = 0; j < itemcount; j++) {
        BarEntry entry = new BarEntry(rand.nextInt(22) + 0, j);
        entries1.add(entry);
        String timeString = formatter.format(j * 3600*24*1000);
        labels1.add(timeString);
    }

    dataset1.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color1));
    dataset1.setHighLightColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color2));
    dataset1.setBarSpacePercent(0f);

    BarData d = new BarData(labels0);
    d.addDataSet(dataset0);
    d.addDataSet(dataset1);
    d.setGroupSpace(300f);

    return d;
}
```

Comment: So it looks that in general Combined Chart with 2 or more bardatasets added via one Bar data are not working good, including Axis problems, barclick problems..

Comment: And after some googling it looks that it is known issue, which is under development, hopefully will be released soon https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/449

Answer (score 0):

Space between individual bars:

barDataSet.setBarSpacePercent(...);

Space between DataSets:

barData.setGroupSpace(...);

Values in percent.

Source Link : https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/197